# Mapping Wordnet Senses to Verbnet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

http://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc30973/m2/1/high_res_d/Mihalcea-2005-Putting_Pieces_Together-Combining_FrameNet.pdf

In the link above on the sixth page, the paper mentions that a mapping was made.

> "The process of mapping VerbNet to WordNet is thus semi-automatic. We
>   first manually link all semantic constraints defined in VerbNet (there are 36
>   such constraints) to one or more nodes in the WordNet semantic hierarchy."

I am trying to use this mapping on NLTK Python with Verbnet and Wordnet. What is the code used for this mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping can be found on Rada Mihalcea's page: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/downloads.html, the direct link: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/downloads/FnWnVerbMap1.0.tar.gz

There are codes for:

- Verbnet: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/verbnet.html
- Framenet: http://www.nltk.org/howto/framenet.html
- Wordnet: http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

But there is no code in NLTK to read the mappings (at least not yet).