# Map wordNet sense key to VerbNet

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

How to get the verb class id given the wordNet sense key using NLTK.

For example:
extracting the verb class id from this wordnet sense key: take.v.01

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323849/mapping-wordnet-senses-to-verbnet

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code that you can share?

Comment: I tried to do something like this: verbnet.classids(wordnetid='take.v.01')

Comment: Also I  tried to do this: wn.synset('take.v.01').lemmas()[0].key() , this gave me 'take%2:41:04::'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
verbnet.classids(wordnetid='run%2:38:00')
```